# How to deserialize json array when i don't know what class i use?

Tags: c#, json

I have a json

```
var j = @"
    [{"Name":"John","Age":27},
     {"Name":"Mike","Age":30},
     {"Name":"Eric","Age":21}
    ]";
```

And class:

```
public class Worker
{
    public string Name{set;get;}
    public int Age{set;get;}
}
```

And how i can deserialize it with `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
List<Worker> videogames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Worker>>(j);
```

But what if i don't know what class I want to deserialize and have just a type?

```
var worker = new Worker();
Type myType = worker.GetType();
```

How can i deserialize this json string in this case?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The other question asks something different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` overload](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm) that accepts a `Type`, passing in a constructed list type:

```
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(myType);
object list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, listType);
```

Of course you won't be able to use that in a statically-type-safe way afterwards - something is likely to need to cast it - but that's unavoidable if you're trying to use a type only known at execution time.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you are deserialising an object that is a list of a specific type, and you are aware of the name of the type you are using, then you can use generics to give you something strictly typed. For example:

```
public static List<T> DeserializeJsonList<T>(string json) 
{
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
}
```

And to use something like this, you could write:

```
string myJson = "[json goes here]";
List<MyType> myList = DeserializeJsonList<MyType>(string json);
```

However, if the type is anonymous (you only have a `Type` object instance, then you will likely have to resort to Jon Skeet's answer instead.